# How to make visual representations of objects in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I start with example:
Let's imagine that I have some application similar to PowerDesigner. It have class Table, which has some parameters.

I would like to make visual representation of object derived from Table on some background. It should be drag and drop in the same way like in PowerDesigner.

Is there some (CDDL) library for this purpose?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Netbeans and IntelliJ comes with neat GUI builders. What is your IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the Java Swing Framework.

This [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/) shows you how to get started and has a chapter on [drag-and-drop](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/draganddrop/).

Answer (score 0):

I found some tutorial which seems like exactly what I want.

http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-visual_library.html

but still, i would like to prefer some library where I can use predefined objects and make it more easy.